# Azure release pipeline not able to see Terraform configuration file from git repo

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Created a simple Azure devops release pipeline to provision a resource group. Tested terraform script with remote state file locally and checked in the code to git. This is how the code is organized:
IAC (root folder)
/bin/terraform.exe
main.tf (this has terraform configuration with remote state)

Created a release pipeline pointing to this repository as code. Pipleline gives the alias _IAC to the artifact

in the pipeline I have powershell activities to login to azure using a service principal

then the following line:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_IAC/bin/terraform init
```

This command executes but says there is no terraform configuration file.

```
2020-03-05T02:23:04.4536130Z [0m[1mTerraform initialized in an empty directory![0m
2020-03-05T02:23:04.4536786Z 
2020-03-05T02:23:04.4556953Z The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
2020-03-05T02:23:04.4559693Z with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

the working directory where azure release pipeline agent is running did not have the configuration file.
I had to use a copy operation to copy the main.tf file to the $(AgentWorkingDirectory)